# JSON Trouble cannot convert to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I know that there are many answers about JSON Arrays but in this case the difference is I found an Android example using JSON when I run it works perfectly, it has 3 classes. Each of them makes a PHP request to a website, which returns a JSON, then the program parses it and makes a list view, my problem is when I run the program it works well using the URLs that came with the default project. But when I use the same PHP code in another server for my own project it returns nothing and log cat says that it cannot be converted to JSONArray

This is the code that works fine:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.androidhive.helper.AlertDialogManager;
import com.example.androidhive.helper.ConnectionDetector;
import com.example.androidhive.helper.JSONParser;

public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {
// Connection detector
ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

// albums JSONArray
JSONArray albums = null;

// albums JSON url
private static final String URL_ALBUMS = " http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php";

// ALL JSON node names
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check for internet connection
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Para poder estar actualizado con los eventos por favor, conéctese a Internet.", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Hashmap for ListView
    albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
    new LoadAlbums().execute();

    // get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    /**
     * Listview item click listener
     * TrackListActivity will be lauched by passing album id
     * */
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // on selecting a single album
            // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

            // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
            String album_id = ((TextView)       view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });     
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
 * */
class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Adquiriendo días. ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Albums JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {               
            albums = new JSONArray(json);

            if (albums != null) {
                // looping through All albums
                for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item values in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    albumsList.add(map);
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                        R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {
                                R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

You will notice at the begining of the code it says

```
private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php"
```

that is the URL I want to change for my own code.

There are 2 PHP files, albums.php and data.php which stores all the information.

albums.php

```
<?php



include_once './data.php';
$albums = array();

// looping through each album
foreach ($album_tracks as $album) {
$tmp = array();
$tmp["id"] = $album["id"];
$tmp["name"] = $album["album"];
$tmp["songs_count"] = count($album["songs"]);

// push album
array_push($albums, $tmp);
}

// printing json
echo json_encode($albums);
?>
```

and data.php

```
<?php


$album_tracks = array(
1 => array(
    "id" => 1,
    "album" => "127 Hours",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Never Hear Surf Music Again", "duration" => "5:52"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "The Canyon", "duration" => "3:01"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Liberation Begins", "duration" => "2:14"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "Touch of the Sun", "duration" => "4:39"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "Lovely Day", "duration" => "4:16"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "Ca Plane Pour Moi", "duration" => "3:00"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "Liberation In A Dream", "duration" => "4:06"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "If You Love Me (Really Love Me)", "duration" => "3:27"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Acid Darbari", "duration" => "4:21"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "R.I.P.", "duration" => "5:11"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "Festival", "duration" => "9:26"),
        array("id" => 12, "name" => "If I Rise", "duration" => "4:38"),
        array("id" => 13, "name" => "Liberation", "duration" => "3:11"),
        array("id" => 14, "name" => "Nocturne No. 2 in E flat", "duration" => "4:01")
    )
),
2 => array(
    "id" => 2,
    "album" => "Adele 21",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Rolling In The Deep", "duration" => "03:48"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "Rumour Has It", "duration" => "03:43"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Turning Tables", "duration" => "04:10"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "Don’t You Remember", "duration" => "04:03"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "Set Fire To The Rain", "duration" => "04:02"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "He Won’t Go", "duration" => "04:38"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "Take It All", "duration" => "03:48"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "I’ll Be Waiting", "duration" => "04:01"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "One And Only", "duration" => "05:48"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "Lovesong", "duration" => "05:16"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "Someone Like You", "duration" => "04:45")
    )
),
3 => array(
    "id" => 3,
    "album" => "Lana Del Rey - Born to Die",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Born to Die", "duration" => "4:46"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "Off to the Races", "duration" => "5:00"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Blue Jeans", "duration" => "3:29"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "Video Games", "duration" => "4:42"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "Diet Mountain Dew", "duration" => "3:43"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "National Anthem", "duration" => "3:51"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "Dark Paradise", "duration" => "4:03"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "Radio", "duration" => "3:35"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Carmen", "duration" => "4:09"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "Million Dollar Man", "duration" => "3:50"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "Summertime Sadness", "duration" => "4:25"),
        array("id" => 12, "name" => "This Is What Makes Us Girls", "duration" => "4:00")
    )
),
4 => array(
    "id" => 4,
    "album" => "Once",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Falling Slowly", "duration" => "4:05"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "If You Want Me", "duration" => "3:47"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Broken Hearted Hoover Fixer Sucker Guy", "duration" => "0:52"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "When Your Mind's Made Up", "duration" => "3:42"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "Lies", "duration" => "3:58"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "Gold", "duration" => "3:59"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "The Hill", "duration" => "4:34"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "Fallen From The Sky", "duration" => "3:24"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Leave", "duration" => "2:46"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "Trying To Pull Myself Away", "duration" => "3:35"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "All The Way Down", "duration" => "2:38"),
        array("id" => 12, "name" => "Once", "duration" => "3:37"),
        array("id" => 13, "name" => "Say It To Me Now", "duration" => "2:36")
    )
),
5 => array(
    "id" => 5,
    "album" => "Away We Go",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "All My Days", "duration" => "4:56"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "Blue Mind", "duration" => "5:42"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "What Is Life", "duration" => "4:24"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "Song For You", "duration" => "4:37"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "Golden Brown", "duration" => "3:31"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "Towards The Sun", "duration" => "4:40"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "Meet Me In The Morning", "duration" => "4:22"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "Breathe", "duration" => "4:16"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Wait", "duration" => "5:55"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "The Ragged Sea", "duration" => "3:20"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "Oh! Sweet Nuthin'", "duration" => "7:29"),
        array("id" => 12, "name" => "Orange Sky", "duration" => "6:09"),
        array("id" => 13, "name" => "Crinan Wood", "duration" => "5:45")
    )
),
6 => array(
    "id" => 6,
    "album" => "Eminem Curtain Call",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "My Name Is", "duration" => "4:28"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "The Way I Am", "duration" => "4:51"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Lose Yourself", "duration" => "5:21"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "Shake That", "duration" => "4:34"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "Sing For The Moment", "duration" => "5:40"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "Without Me", "duration" => "4:47"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "Like Toy Soldiers", "duration" => "4:51"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "The Real Slim Shady", "duration" => "4:44"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Mockingbird", "duration" => "4:11"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "Guilty Conscience", "duration" => "3:19"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "Cleanin' Out My Closet", "duration" => "4:58"),
        array("id" => 12, "name" => "Just Lose It", "duration" => "4:08"),
        array("id" => 13, "name" => "When I'm Gone", "duration" => "4:40"),
        array("id" => 14, "name" => "Stan", "duration" => "6:21")
    )
),
7 => array(
    "id" => 7,
    "album" => "Bad Meets Evil Eminem",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Lighters", "duration" => "5:21"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "Fast Lane", "duration" => "3:19"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Above the Law", "duration" => "6:21"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "Welcome 2 Hell", "duration" => "4:34"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "Take from Me", "duration" => "4:51"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "The Reunion", "duration" => "4:44"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "A Kiss", "duration" => "3:19"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "Echo", "duration" => "6:21"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Lighters", "duration" => "4:40"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "Living Proof", "duration" => "3:49"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "Loud Noises", "duration" => "3:19")
    )
),
8 => array(
    "id" => 8,
    "album" => "Safe Trip Home",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Don't Believe in Love", "duration" => "3:52"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "Quiet Times", "duration" => "3:16"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Never Want to Say It's Love", "duration" => "3:34"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "Grafton Street", "duration" => "5:56"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "It Comes And It Goes", "duration" => "3:26"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "Look No Further", "duration" => "3:15"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "Us 2 Little Gods", "duration" => "4:48"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "The Day Before The Day", "duration" => "4:12"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Let's Do the Things We Normally Do", "duration" => "4:08"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "Burnin Love", "duration" => "4:10"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "Northern Skies", "duration" => "8:53")
    )
),
9 => array(
    "id" => 9,
    "album" => "No Angel",
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Here With Me", "duration" => "4:05"),
        array("id" => 2, "name" => "Hunter", "duration" => "3:55"),
        array("id" => 3, "name" => "Don't Think Of Me", "duration" => "4:32"),
        array("id" => 4, "name" => "My Lover's Gone", "duration" => "4:27"),
        array("id" => 5, "name" => "All You Want", "duration" => "3:53"),
        array("id" => 6, "name" => "Thank You", "duration" => "3:36"),
        array("id" => 7, "name" => "Honestly Ok", "duration" => "4:37"),
        array("id" => 8, "name" => "Slide", "duration" => "4:50"),
        array("id" => 9, "name" => "Isobel", "duration" => "3:55"),
        array("id" => 10, "name" => "I'm No Angel", "duration" => "3:55"),
        array("id" => 11, "name" => "My Life", "duration" => "2:59"),
        array("id" => 12, "name" => "Take My Hand", "duration" => "6:50")
    )
    )
);
?>
```

Well I stored the PHP files in a dropbox public folder and tried to change the first url api.androidhive.../songs/albums.php

For the new one where PHP is stored in dropbox
"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105156121/albums.php"

But when I changed the server where it is allocated it only returns me blank.

Comment: Open your url - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105156121/albums.php
at this dropboxusercontet there is NO PHP running and its opened as plain text (so no JSON at all).. You need a web server with a PHP..

Comment: hi , thx youre right i forgot to mention that i have already wrote tha path , but  do you have any idea of were can i upload this files for making them work ? ???